# Dynamic entries from textfiles into FlowLayoutPanel

Tags: vb.net, dynamic, controls

I'm currently working on a ToDo program, where you can simply add notes. (With the option to set priority and attachment) The Note will be saved as a textfile. Now I want to make an over view of the ToDo's which have to be done. In the end it's supposed to look like a list, one row for each Note, built like this:

> TITLE.............................[Attachment Icon]..[Priority Icon]..[CheckBox]

The checkbox should always be on the very right side of the row.

My idea is to add a FlowLayoutPanel to a FlowLayoutPanel for every Note. In the child-FlowLayoutPanel I'll add the controls. My problem is that I have no Idea how to set the positions of the controls. I tried to add a label and use it as a space between the title and the other controls, but it doesn't really work.

Here's the code I currently have:

```
For Each File In Directory.GetFiles(myPath)
        Dim tlp As New FlowLayoutPanel
        tlp.BackColor = Color.Gray
        tlp.Width = 260
        tlp.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.TopDown

        Dim lbl As New Label
        lbl.AutoSize = True
        lbl.Text = getInsert(File, 0)
        lbl.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Right
        lbl.ForeColor = Color.White
        AddHandler lbl.Click, Sub() Me.getInsert(File, 0)

        tlp.Height = 40

        Dim cbx As New CheckBox
        cbx.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat
        cbx.Text = ""
        cbx.Width = 15
        cbx.Height = 30
        AddHandler cbx.CheckStateChanged, Sub() Me.deleteEntry(tlp)


        Dim space As New Label
        space.AutoSize = False
        space.Text = ""
        space.Height = 30
        space.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Right

        tlp.Controls.Add(lbl)
        tlp.Controls.Add(Space)
        tlp.Controls.Add(cbx)
        Space.Width = tlp.Width - lbl.Width - cbx.Width - 15
        mfp.Controls.Add(tlp)
Next
```

Here's an example:
[todo_example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BX3v1.jpg)

I hope anyone has a good idea how to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You should design a user control that represents a single record. You can then simply create instances of that control and add them to the one `FlowLayoutPanel`.

Comment: You might also consider just using a `DataGridView`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I made a form. But I can't add it to the FlowLayoutPanel: "mfp.Controls.Add(form_name)" In the debugger it just cancels the sub when it reaches the line and does nothing.

Comment: A form? I said a user control.